# Consequences of turning on pruning setting in Bitcoin core after initial block download

Tags: bitcoin-core, full-node, pruning

I have been running full node without specifying the pruning settings in bitcoin.conf.

I was wondering if I need to re-download the entire blockchain if I restart my node after **turning on** pruning settings?

Comment: I'd be astonished if the answer was anything other than turning pruning on causes deletion of all existing blockfiles (except those containing the most recent 288 blocks) and that it does not ever re-download the data it has just deleted. Not having done this I can't be absolutely sure this part of the software was written by a sane person but gosh - wow, surely it was!?

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick: thanks a lot for editing and responding my question and sorry about the ambiguity, would you please post your comment as an answer so I can mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, when turning on pruning for a node with a full copy of the blockchain, it simply discards the oldest part of the blockchain down to the specified limit of what's to be kept.

You only need to download from scratch, if you turn off pruning or when you need to rescan or resync.